# Joomla missing component

Tags: installation, joomla, components, missing-features

I have an installation (3.4.8) who it's missing `com_joomlaupdate` component. It has removed. It has upgraded from a previous 2.x version.

Can I reinstall manually? Or how can I fix situation?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, then you owe it to yourself to register an account on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Every time you have a question that directly pertains to Joomla or would benefit from receiving support from a dedicated community of volunteers with an intimdate understanding of the CMS and its extensions, please post your question on JSE instead of Stack Overflow.  JSE does not get enough daily questions.  https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842?phase=beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The install package for the Joomla Update Component can be downloaded and installed as you would with any extension.

Joomla Update can be downloaded from:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.6.1/com_joomlaupdate-3.6.1.zip